# MobileFirst Obtain Access token and Login give no response after setting WL.App.setServerURL

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

As per my requirement, I am using `WL.APP.setServerURL` before every login request `WLAuthorizationManager.login`of mobilefirst.

When I do first an valid/Invalid login attempt it works fine. As on next attempt I do `WL.App.setServerURL`, and then WLAuthorizationManager.login (login request) OR `WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken` (obtain access token request) don't respond anything. No success and no fail. Although non-secure adapter method works fine.

If I do `WL.APP.setServerURL` only once on application startup, everything works fine but in between call cause application failure.

```
let url = ... //fetcht url from adapter call
WL.App.setServerUrl(url, function (sucess) {
  WLAuthorizationManager.login(securityCheckName, loginParam).then((data) => {
     .... //After login code
    }, (response) => {
      //Login fail code
    });

}, function (error) {


});
```

Flow :-
    I call above code on click of login button.I call a method to get server url from adapter first then I set that url as server url.
    When I do an invalid attempt of login it works find for first time, and on next call MFP login, it doesn't respond. Not success nor fail in application.

I am getting error in native logs android.

```
Android Error logs :-
E/SecurityCheckChallengeHandler(30199): SecurityCheckChallengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer in SecurityCheckChallengeHandler.java:51 :: submitAnswer has been called for unknown request
```

.

```
MobileFirst server version :- 8.0.0.00-20170911-123510
MobileFirst Cordova(plugin) version :- 8.0.2017102403
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The `WL.App.setServerUrl` API is meant to be used sparingly whenever the app needs to connect to a server other than the one defined in mfpclient.properties. If you want to keep the server URL constant, you should just put it up in the `mfpclient.properties`.

Having said that, the behaviour you mention is not expected - can you update your question with a code snippet of your app performing login & setServerUrl

Comment: Added android log as well